# Finding implicit form of Nyquist curve without using a general algorithm for Groebner bases.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, rational-functions, groebner-basis, implicit-function

According to [Conversion Methods Between Parametric and Implicit Curves and Surfaces, by Christoph N1. Hoffmann](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs348a-20-winter/Handouts/a228715.pdf) p.3

> Every plane parametric curve can be expressed as an implicit curve.

In problems related to control theory, we often need to create a Nyquist plot from a transfer function. To do so, we first substitute $j\omega$ for $s$ in the transfer function. (Engineers use $j$ where mathematicians use $i$.)

For example, if we are given the transfer function

$$F(s)=\frac{1}{as^2 + bs + c}$$

we generate the new function

$$G(\omega)=\frac{1}{a(j\omega)^2+b(j\omega)+c} =\frac{1}{(c-a\omega^2)+jb\omega}=\frac{(c-a\omega^2)-jb\omega}{(c-a\omega^2)^2-(jb\omega)^2}=\frac{(c-a\omega^2)-jb\omega}{(c-a\omega^2)^2+(b\omega)^2} $$

The next step is to separate the real and imaginary parts of this function

$$G_r(\omega) = Re(G(\omega)) = \frac{(c-a\omega^2)}{(c-a\omega^2)^2+(b\omega)^2}$$

$$G_i(\omega) = Im(G(\omega)) = \frac{-b\omega}{(c-a\omega^2)^2+(b\omega)^2}$$

This gives a parameterized curve $(G_r(\omega),G_i(\omega))$, which when plotted is known as a Nyquist plot. The Nyquist plot is useful for determining the stability of a system.

There are software packages that will quickly give a Nyquist plot for a given transfer function. For example [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Nyquist%20plot%20%281%2F%28s%5E2%2Bs%2B1%29%29) has a Nyquist method. This tool shows the Nyquist plot for $1/(s^2+s+1)$ as a cardiod-like curve. (The transfer function $1/(s^2+2s+1)$ would give a "true" cardiod Nyquist plot.)

[image]

While plotting is useful, it is sometimes desirable to know the implicit equation (level set equation) for the parametric curve defined by $(G_r(\omega),G_i(\omega))$

It is possible to find such an implicit equation using Groebner bases.

For example, we can rearrange the algebraic equations

$$x = \frac{P_r(\omega)}{P_d(\omega)}$$
$$y = \frac{P_i(\omega)}{P_d(\omega)}$$

to

$$xP_d(\omega) - P_r(\omega) = 0$$
$$yP_d(\omega) - P_i(\omega) = 0$$

And then find a Groebner basis for the polynomials

$$\{xP_d(\omega) - P_r(\omega),\; yP_d(\omega) - P_i(\omega)\}$$

Continuing with our example of

$$G(\omega)=\frac{(c-a\omega^2)-jb\omega}{(c-a\omega^2)^2+(b\omega)^2}$$

We wish to find a Groebner basis for

$$\{x((c-a\omega^2)^2+(b\omega)^2)- (c-a\omega^2),\;\; y((c-a\omega^2)^2+(b\omega)^2))+b\omega\}$$

if we choose $a=b=c=1$ then we have

$$\{x((1-\omega^2)^2+\omega^2)-(1-\omega^2),\;\; y((1-\omega^2)^2+\omega^2)+\omega\}=\{x(\omega^4-\omega^2+1)-(1-\omega^2),\;\; y(\omega^4-\omega^2+1)+\omega\}$$

We can again use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%7Bx%28w%5E4-w%5E2%2B1%29%20%2B1-%20w%5E2%2C%20y%28w%5E4-w%5E2%2B1%29-w%7D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%7D%2C%7Bw%7D%5D) to find the Groebner basis polynomial with $\omega$ eliminated. The result given is:

$${x^4 - x^3 + 2 x^2 y^2 - x y^2 + y^4 - y^2}$$

and setting that polynomial equal to $0$ seems to give the implicit equation for our Nyquist curve.

[image]

Which gives us the same cardiod-like curve.

Suppose I wanted to calculate the implicit form for the Nyquist curve by hand. If I follow the procedure just outlined, I would use the algorithm for finding Groebner bases. It is my understanding that this algorithm involves tedious search. But I know something about the Nyquist curve besides it's parametric form. I also know that it was derived by splitting the complex extension of a rational function into real and imaginary parts. I am hoping this fact gives me some leverage to simplify the algorithm for finding the implicit equation for the Nyquist curve.

And that, in essence is my question.

Knowing that $F(s)$ is a rational function with real co-efficients, and that $F(j\omega) = G_r(\omega) + jG_i(\omega)$, is there an algorithm to find the implicit form (level set form) of the curve defined parametrically by points $(G_r(\omega), G_i(\omega))$ without using a *general* algorithm for calculating Groebner bases? (That is, is there an algorithm that is *specialized* to this particular problem.)

Comment: See the Wikipedia entry for the Resultant of two polynomials. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant In particular  consult the subsection Other Applications/Algebraic Geometry/ Parametrization of Rational Curves